# How do i implement an endless scroll to onResume()?

Tags: android

How do i implement an endless scroll to onResume(), currently onCreateView, I implement an endless Scroll and it works just fine but when it comes to onResume(), it doesn't work in another it shows blank data.

here's the code for onCreate

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(com.barakah.camel.R.layout.browse_fragment_layout,
                container, false);
        setupFloatingActionMenu(getActivity());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView
                .findViewById(com.barakah.camel.R.id.my_recycler_view);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(
                layoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                int limit = current_page * 5;
                LoadMoreItems(limit);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Here's the code for onResume()

```
public View onResume(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        super.onResume();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(com.barakah.camel.R.layout.browse_fragment_layout,
                container, false);
        setupFloatingActionMenu(getActivity());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView
                .findViewById(com.barakah.camel.R.id.my_recycler_view);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(
                layoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                int limit = current_page * 5;
                LoadMoreItems(limit);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Any help would be appreaciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onResume()` method does not correctly override the method of the same name as found in `Activity` or `Fragment`.

The method shouldn't return a `View` as it is a `void` method. Something *like* this may be what you are after:

i.e.:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(layoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            int limit = current_page * 5;
            LoadMoreItems(limit);
        }
    });
}
```